# DateTime::createFromFormat issue

Tags: php, datetime

I dont know why I am getting this error or how to fix it.

```
Call to a member function format() on a non-object createFromFormat
```

Code:

```
$date = "30 Sep 2009";
$data['StartDate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d m Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

I want to convert it to standard MySql Date format.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `M` instead of `m` for `createFromFormat()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is likely due to the fact that "m" is the code for two digit month--not textual representation, which is "M".

Have you, by any chance, tried simply passing that string into the DateTime constructor? The format is one of the accepted ones per http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php .

```
$date = new DateTime("30 Sep 2009");
$data['StartDate'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: My test machine was running 5.3.5, but I have servers that use similar code that run ~5.2.6. Looking at the DateTime::__construct() page, it says you must be running 5.2.0 or greater.

Comment: Problem fixed to lowercase the month, 30 Sep 2009 to 30 sep 2009

Comment: My problem was due to a forgotten `setLocale()`